# How can I efficiently compute the mean of X@W in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, out-of-memory, vectorization, linear-algebra

I have a sparse (CSR format) matrix, X, with shape 90,708 by 8000 and a dense 8000 by 8000 matrix W and want to efficiently calculate the result of the following procedure:

1. Multiply X by W to get a new 98,708 by 8000 matrix,
2. Apply ReLU element-wise,
3. Find the mean of each column to get a 8000 long row vector.

Unfortunately, I don't have enough memory on my GPU to calculate the result using the steps described above. When I try to perform the computation in PyTorch, using the code `x = torch.mean(self.relu(torch.sparse.mm(x, self.weights1)), 0)`, I get the following error: `RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 978.00 MiB (GPU 0; 4.00 GiB total capacity; 2.95 GiB already allocated; 0 bytes free; 2.97 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF`.

Now, it should be possible to calculate the result in a different way, for example by iterating through the 8000 columns of W, and on each iteration, multiplying the column vector by X, applying ReLU and taking the mean. Is there a more efficient/cleaner way to perform the required procedure?

Answer (score 0):

As you noted you can process by parts to reduce peak GPU memory usage. You can use [torch.chunk](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.chunk.html) to split the dense `w` matrix into groups of columns as it may be more efficient than processing each column individually.

Example:

```
import torch
from scipy import sparse

csr = sparse.random(90708, 8000, density=0.001, format="csr")
x = torch.sparse_csr_tensor(csr.indptr, csr.indices, csr.data, size=csr.shape, dtype=torch.float32).cuda()
w = torch.rand((8000, 8000)).cuda()


out_chunked = []
for w_chunk in torch.chunk(w, chunks=10, dim=1):
    out_chunked.append(torch.mean(torch.relu(torch.sparse.mm(x, w_chunk)), 0))
out_chunked = torch.cat(out_chunked)


out_full = torch.mean(torch.relu(torch.sparse.mm(x.cuda(), w)), 0)
assert torch.allclose(out_full, out_chunked)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Do you know of any way to get PyTorch to automatically choose the "optimal" number of chunks, i.e. to have as few chunks as possible while still fitting everything in memory?